# Nature of Javadocs, and importing them to NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc, gate

I have downloaded GATE, a set of tools to help with natural language processing, with the intent of creating an named entity extractor in Java.

I have successfully imported the jar files into my Netbeans project. The Javadocs are not being displayed.

I have never in the past imported javadocs into Netbeans (or any IDE for that matter), and am not sure what they should look like.

Included with the gate download were javadocs. These javadocs seem to be HTML files and are located in doc/javadoc from the main folder containing GATE.  The javadoc folder has several folder contained within it.

After doing a little bit of research, I have tried several methods:

1)
Tools->Java Platforms->Javadoc->Add ZIP/Folder... and adding the javadoc folder (Attempt 1), the doc folder (Attempt 2), and several of the folders within.

2)
Adding these same folders to the associated .jar files/folders under the Libraries section of the project window.

It seems from the prompt in Netbeans that these javadocs are supposed to be .jar/zip files... I did not find any of these that I believed contained javadocs in my download.

My questions are:

1)
What is the format of a javadoc? They seem to be very many HTML files from what I can see, and matching them individually seems like it would be annoying.

2)
Can I import these files into Netbeans to help my development? Or will I have to search for the appropriate HTML file and open it when I want information about an object/method/etc...?

Do not hesitate to ask for clarification or additional information.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: There are several ways, depending on how you've loaded the Jar library.  If you've just added the jar directly to the project, you can right click on it's entry under the "Libraries" node of the project and select "Edit...".  You will have three tabs, "Classpath", "Sources" and "JavaDoc".  Select the "Javadoc" tab.  You can add a jar or zip file containing the JavaDocs or a URL to the JavaDocs on line.  I prefer to add a jar/zip file of the docs, as it's quicker to load then using a URL

Comment: Thank you for your reply, MadProgrammer. As stated in the OP, I have tried this method.

Comment: Could you clarify what URL I would use? Would the below work, for example?

Comment: I keep hitting enter meaning to newline but I add the comment... anyways, here's the url: https://gate.ac.uk/releases/gate-3.1-build2270-ALL/doc/javadoc/

Comment: That looks okay to me